# How to find cointegrating vectors

Tags: time-series, self-study, econometrics, cointegration

How to find cointegrating vectors and how many vectors could there be if $e_t\ $, $p_t\ $ and $p_t^\ast\ $ are cointegrated?

$
e_t\ =\ p_t\ -\ p_t^\ast\ +\ v_t
$

$
p_t\ =\ p_{t-1}+\ u_{2t}
$

$
p_t^\ast\ =\ p_{t-1}+\ u_{1t}
$

$
v_t\sim iid(0,\sigma_v),  u_{it}\sim I\left(0\right)$ for $i=1,2$.

Solution:

$
A^\prime z\ =\ \left[\begin{matrix}e_t\\p_t^\ast\\p_t\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}1&-1&1\\0&1&-1\\\end{matrix}\right]\sim I(0)
$

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, add the [tag:self-study] and read its [Wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. A cointegrating vector contains coefficients that produce a linear combination of I(1) variables that is I(0). It is common to normalize the first coefficient to 1.
2. A system of 3 integrated variables that are also cointegrated can have either 1 or 2 cointegrating vectors. (If it had 3, the 3 series could not be integrated to begin with. If it had 0, the 3 series would not be cointegrated.)
3. $p_t$ and $p_t^*$ seem to be highly related. What about the linear combination $p_t-p_t^*$?
4. If $e_t$, $p_t$ and $p_t^*$ are cointegrated, there exists a linear combination that is I(0). What about the linear combination that yields $v_t$?

Comment: Thank you so much for the hints! I've added my attempt to solve it. Could you please kindly tell is it correct?

Comment: @Aella, looks good to me.